# How to download xml file generated using builder to save as an xml file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have tried by using following code in my index controller

```
    def index
      @forms = Form.all
      data = render_to_string( :action => :index )
      send_data data, :filename => "xyz.xml", :disposition => 'attachment'
    end
```

but it is saving object id's but not the xml output with values.

I want to save the output which i can see in index.xml.builder in views

This is index.xml.builder view

```
    xml.instruct! :xml, :version => "1.0", :encoding => 'UTF-8'

    @forms.each do |form|
      xml.admin do
        xml.applicant_info do
          xml.id form.form_id
          xml.company_name form.company_name
          xml.submission_description form.submission_description

      form.applicants.each do |applicant|
            xml.applicant_contacts do
              xml.applicant_contact do
                xml.applicant_contact_name applicant.applicant_contact_name, :'applicant-contact-type' => applicant.applicant_contact_type 
                xml.telephones do
                  xml.telephone applicant.telephone, :'telephone-number-type' => applicant.telephone_number_type
                end 
                xml.emails do
                  xml.email applicant.email
                end 
              end
            end
          end
        end
        xml.application_set do
          xml.application_containing_files form.application_containing_files
          xml.application_information do
            xml.application_number form.application_number, :'application-type' => form.application_type 
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried:
`send_data data.to_xml . . .`

Comment: @RunsnbunsN Thanks for the reply. Yes I did and this is the output I got

undefined method `to_xml' for #<ActionView::OutputBuffer:0x00007f95faddcfb0> Did you mean? to_yaml

Comment: Where is your builder generated xml? You are sending a string representation of the view of `index` action. Could you please show your view file.

Comment: @mehedi Added index.xml.builder view to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than writing xml builder in your action view can you write that code in a private method in your action.

```
def index
  @forms = Form.all
  send_data build_xml.to_xml, :filename => "xyz.xml", :disposition => 'attachment'
end 

private

def build_xml
  Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.root do
      @forms.each do |form|
        xml.admin do
          xml.applicant_info do
            xml.id form.form_id
            xml.company_name form.company_name
            xml.submission_description form.submission_description

        form.applicants.each do |applicant|
              xml.applicant_contacts do
                xml.applicant_contact do
                  xml.applicant_contact_name applicant.applicant_contact_name, :'applicant-contact-type' => applicant.applicant_contact_type 
                  xml.telephones do
                    xml.telephone applicant.telephone, :'telephone-number-type' => applicant.telephone_number_type
                  end 
                  xml.emails do
                    xml.email applicant.email
                  end 
                end
              end
            end
          end
          xml.application_set do
            xml.application_containing_files form.application_containing_files
            xml.application_information do
              xml.application_number form.application_number, :'application-type' => form.application_type 
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!!

Also instead of xml.applicant_info if i use as xml.applicant-info I'm getting error as rails is treating hyphen as minus. but if i want it to be - in xml how to do that?

Comment: @Ruby4Rails `xml.tag!('applicant-info')`